# Exceptions for control flow

Tags: javascript, jquery, exception-handling, jquery-ui

I just wrote the following javascript (jQeury loaded):

```
var valid, ui;

try {
    $.each(this._cache, function() {
        $.each(this, function() {
            $.each(this, function() {
                if (this.label.toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase) {
                    valid = true;
                    ui = {item: $.extend({}, this) };
                    throw 'Control flow throw, please rethrow if accidently caught';
                }
            });
        });
    });
} catch(e) {}
```

My coworker suggested I rewrite this as follows:

```
var valid, ui;

$.each(this._cache, function() {
    $.each(this, function() {
        $.each(this, function() {
            if (this.label.toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase) {
                valid = true;
                ui = {item: $.extend({}, this) };
            }
            return !valid;
        });
        return !valid;
    });
    return !valid;
});
```

I think this is a valid case of using exceptions as control flow. Which way is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Exceptions should be used in exceptional circumstances, not in logic of the application.  By exceptional circumstances, I mean they should only be used when something unexpected happens.

Answer (score 3):

As Jef Vanzella mentioned, exceptions are for unexpected bad things, not for jumping out of control flow. Hence the second option is better, but it is still substandard code.

Instead of using `this`, you should have a meaningful parameter name in your function declaration.

Also, you could simply return the falsey `!ui` instead of `!valid`.

Finally, not many people know that returning `false` stops the iteration, that deserves a comment.

Now imagine that your data structure was `Cache -> Orders -> Shipments -> Items` then you could write:

```
var ui;

//Returning false to each() will stop the iteration
$.each(this._cache, function( order ) {
    $.each(order, function( shipment ) {
        $.each(shipment, function( item) {
            if (item.label.toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase) {
                ui = {item: $.extend({}, this) };
            }
            return !ui ;
        });
        return !ui ;
    });
    return !ui ;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with [tomdemuyt](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/38759/2634) but I'd take a different approach altogether.

Instead of iterating through objects with jQuery, I'd use [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org) and focus on *working with data*.
Undercore provides more convenience methods to filter and transform data than jQuery.

There is also no rightward code drift if the data structure gets more complex in the future.

Assuming `Cache -> Orders -> Shipments -> Items` data structure and that you iterate over object properties (and not arrays), it would be something like:

```
var orders = _.chain(this._cache).values(),
    shipments = orders.map(_.values).flatten(),
    items = shipments.map(_.values).flatten(),
    matchingItem,
    ui;

matchingItem = items.find(function (item) {
  return item.label.toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase;
});

if (matchingItem) {
  ui = { item: matchingItem.clone().value() };
}
```

[Run it on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dU699/).

As tomdemuyt suggested, you don't need `valid` because you can check `ui`.

The downside of this method is that although it will *not* run the check for every item, it still has to iterate over each order and shipment to gather their items into a single big array, so it is guaranteed to be slower.

Still, this should not concern you, unless you have thousands of items—and from the point of maintenance I think this is simpler code to work with and extend. I'd prefer more readable code unless this really becomes the bottleneck.

Comment: The only hiccup is that you process all items at all times with `.map()`, always giving worst case performance. Still, +1

Comment: @tomdemuyt Yeah, you're right.